# Where does CLSIDFromProgID() look in the registry?

Tags: com, guid, clsidfromprogid

MS' docs simply say:

> Given a ProgID, CLSIDFromProgID looks up its associated CLSID in the
>   registry.

But where exactly does it look? I have a weird issue where a wrong CLSID is being returned and I want to follow where this function is looking to help narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: It looks in HKCR\progid\CLSID where "progid" is your ProgId string.  It was already clear from your other question that in all likelihood your registration code is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lookup goes through the [application's manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) and its dependant [assembly manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374219(v=vs.85).aspx). This is done to support [registration-free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375134(v=vs.85).aspx).

If there's no application manifest or if none of the dependant assembly manifests declare your class in a `comClass` or `clrClass` XML element, the lookup defaults to the registry, which will check [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<ProgID>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542719(v=vs.85).aspx)<sup>1</sup> with a string value named [`CLSID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688628(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

<sup>1.</sup> `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a mix of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.